# Why IntelliJ IDEA doesn't connect oracle database with java code in maven project?

Tags: java, database, maven, jdbc, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make maven project which should work with oracle database.

First I tried to connect database to DB Browser in IDEA, but I've no idea how to use it in code if it's even possible. However I use following java code:

```
Base.open("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "SYSTEM", "pass");
```

it doesn't run with error Failed to connect to JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified.
```

But according to connection info in DB browser it's written right. What's going wrong?

Comment: your question is not clear.. it will be easier if you post the exception "as is" from your log...

is it a driver/classpath issue?
is it a tnsnames or sql* net issue?
is that oracle db mounted & open ?

Comment: What is your JVM Locale?

Comment: @Blind Despair, IJ DB browser is not same as VisualStudio datasoure/manger-- the db browser in intellij is just there so you have quick sql ide to run queries --

Comment: also, given your errors, can you first try to connect to your oracle XE using sqlplus? and see if you get same errors?  b/c those errors seems independent of JDBC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by following code before `Base.open(...);`: `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: Yes, Oracle XE only supports English, Japanese, Chinese and Portuguese [NLS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#BABGEEDF) (locale) values.